# unexpected token: - near line 1 in JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i am using `spring boot JPA` here is my update query looks like

```
 @Query("update employee set sal=  sal- 1000  where salary > :sal")
 void updateSalary(@Param("sal") Long sal)
```

In service method

```
 List<Employee> updateSalary(Long sal){
   repo.updateSalary(10000l);
   return repo.findAll();
 }
```

Somehow JPA not able to understand `-` character.

Comment: first please tell me do you have service layer ? and maybe you need update the employee by uniq identifier for instance **id**

Comment: @edhi.uchiha yes there is service layer and i want to update salary of all employee based on sal lets say >10000

Comment: Can you show me the service layer code ?

Comment: update employee e set e.sal =  e.sal - 1000  where e.salary > :sal

Comment: Or should it be ```@Query("update employee set salary =  salary - 1000  where salary > :sal")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query should be

```java
@Query("update Employee e set e.salary = e.salary-1000 where e.salary > :arg")
```

Also you have to mark Repository method with `@Transactional` and `@Modifying` and the return type should always be `void`.

Full code:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMysqlApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMysqlApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if (employeeRepository.count() == 0) {
            List<Employee> employees = List.of(
                    new Employee(null, "Josh", 1800L),
                    new Employee(null, "John", 800L),
                    new Employee(null, "Nina", 1500L),
                    new Employee(null, "Nate", 400L)
            );

            employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
        }
    }


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public static class HelloController {

        @Autowired
        EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

        @GetMapping(path = "/")
        public Map<String, String> update() {
            employeeRepository.updateSalary(1000L);
            return Map.of("status", "success");
        }

        @GetMapping(path = "/all")
        public Map<String, Object> all() {
            return Map.of("status", "success", "employees", employeeRepository.findAll());
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update Employee e set e.salary = e.salary-1000 where e.salary > :arg")
    void updateSalary(@Param("arg") Long arg);

}
```